# Updating a two-dimensional array but reprinting it does not show updated values

Tags: c++, arrays, function

I am working on a final project for an intro to C++ class and I am having an issue with a two-dimensional array. I am initializing it with a nested loop and the program is working as intended but when I try to reprint the array it does not show the updated values. It is an airplane seating chart assignment, and when I choose my row/seat it will update the array itself but when I try to reprint it, the chart shows the same data as before. If I try to book the same seat it does recognize that it is no longer available, however. This code isn't remotely finished because I got stuck at this problem and haven't fine tuned the rest of the functionality. For simplicity's sake I've only included the code for the First Class part of the program and the related functions. I think I might be calling the array wrong as a parameter but that doesn't explain why the chart still prints as normal when I recall the printChart function. Like I said if I enter one choice then try to enter it again the program recognizes that it has already been chosen, just the printing of the chart itself will not update.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <iomanip>

using namespace std;

const int ROWS = 13;
const int SEATS = 6;
char chart[ROWS][SEATS];

void initializeChart(char chart[][SEATS], int numOfRows);
void printChart(char chart[][SEATS], int rowStart, int numOfRows);
void chooseSeat(char chart[][SEATS]);
void firstClass(char chart[][SEATS]);
void businessClass(char chart[][SEATS]);
void economyClass(char chart[][SEATS]);
void bookSeat(char chart[][SEATS], int rowChoice, int seatChoice);

int main()
{
    initializeChart(chart, ROWS);
    printChart(chart, 0, ROWS);
    chooseSeat(chart);

    return 0;
}


void initializeChart(char chart[][SEATS], int numOfRows) {

    for (int i = 0; i < numOfRows; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < SEATS; j++) {
            chart[i][j] = '*';
        }
    }
}

void printChart(char chart[][SEATS], int rowStart, int numOfRows) {

    cout << "Seats currently available:" << endl;
    cout << "(* is vacant, X is occupied)" << endl << endl;
    cout << setw(6) << ' ';

    for (char i = 'A'; i <= 'F'; i++)
        cout << setw(5) << i;

    cout << endl;

    for (int i = rowStart; i < numOfRows; i++) {

        cout << "ROW " << i + 1;

        if (i < 9)
            cout << " ";

        for (int j = 0; j < SEATS; j++) 
            cout << setw(5) << chart[i][j];

        cout << endl;
    }
    cout << endl;
}

void chooseSeat(char chart[][SEATS]) {

    char seatClass;

    cout << "Please choose a class(1 for First, 2 for Business, 3 for Economy): ";
    cin >> seatClass;
    cout << endl << endl;

    while (seatClass != '0') {
        if (seatClass == '1') {
            firstClass(chart);
            chooseSeat(chart);
            break;
        }
        else if (seatClass == '2') {
            businessClass(chart);
            break;
        }
        else if (seatClass == '3') {
            economyClass(chart);
            break;
        }
        else {
            cout << "Invalid choice. Choose 1 for First Class, 2 for Business, or 3 for Economy: ";
            cin >> seatClass;
            cout << endl;
        }
    }
}

void firstClass(char chart[][SEATS]) {

    char rowChoice;
    char seatChoice;

    cout << "You have chosen First Class." << endl << endl;
    printChart(chart, 0, 2);
    cout << "Which row would you like?";
    cin >> rowChoice;
    cout << endl << endl;

    while (rowChoice != '0') {
        if (rowChoice == '1' || rowChoice == '2') {
            //static_cast<int>(rowChoice);
            cout << "What seat would you like?";
            cin >> seatChoice;
            cout << endl << endl;

            switch (seatChoice) {
                case 'A':
                    bookSeat(chart, rowChoice, 0);
                    break;
                case 'B':
                    bookSeat(chart, rowChoice, 1);
                    break;
                case 'C':
                    bookSeat(chart, rowChoice, 2);
                    break;
                case 'D':
                    bookSeat(chart, rowChoice, 3);
                    break;
                case 'E':
                    bookSeat(chart, rowChoice, 4);
                    break;
                case 'F':
                    bookSeat(chart, rowChoice, 5);
                    break;
                default:
                    cout << "That is not a valid seat choice. Please enter A - F.";
                    cin >> seatChoice;
                    cout << endl << endl;
            }
        }
        else {

            cout << "This is not a valid choice for First Class. Please re-enter: ";
            cin >> rowChoice;
            cout << endl << endl;
        }
    }
}

void bookSeat(char chart[][SEATS], int rowChoice, int seatChoice) {
    if (chart[rowChoice][seatChoice] != 'X') {
        chart[rowChoice][seatChoice] = 'X';
        cout << "Your seat is booked!" << endl << endl;
        printChart(chart, 0, 2);
    }
    else {
        cout << "Sorry. That seat is occupied. Please choose another.";
        printChart(chart, 0, 2);
    }
}
```

Comment: Please provide the expected output, in addition to actual output, that you receive.

Comment: I could not immediately see your bug, until I ran your program in my debugger. If you don't know how to do this, this is a good opportunity to learn how to use it to run your program one line at a time, monitor all variables and their values as they change, and analyse your program's logical execution. Knowing how to use a debugger is a required skill for every C++ developer, no exceptions. With your debugger's help you should be able to quickly find all bugs in this and all future programs you write. P.S. Major memory corruption, it's amazing this runs at all.

Comment: I dunno if that's fortunate. I like bugs that go boom. Usually they're easier to find.

Comment: I see what you are saying about the rowChoice. I ran it again and added a rowChoice -= 1 but it does not seem to make a difference. If anything I would think that the wrong row would be updated and not the case I have where nothing is changing. I kept running row 1 seat A. The second time through it still recognizes that the seat is booked but the print function still doesn't update properly.

Comment: The key is: `'1'` is different from `1`

Comment: I'm pretty sure the issue I'm having is using char instead of int for some of these values. I decided to go that route because it was easier to control the user input but I think I am going to have to redo those variables.

Comment: 100% was the char input. I am going to have to rewrite most of it to make it work. I was trying to apply the philosophy of "if the user can get it wrong, they will" and the char option seemed easier.

Comment: Thanks everyone for the help. A lot of the assignments thus far have been pretty simple and I haven't really had to use the debugger much. As soon as I put a stop in there and saw the value for rowChoice was "48" i knew what the issue was. Thanks again.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik what memory issues are you referring to?

Comment: The memory issues where one tries to write to the 49th row of an array with only 13 rows.